# Replace element and following elements in a list if condition met

Tags: python, loops

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5,3,2,1,3,1]
```

I am looking for a way that every time it finds a 1, this element AND the next two elements are replaced by -999. The following code seems to work.

```
b = a
x = 2 #number of continuous elements to browse 
for n,i in enumerate(a):
    if i==1:
        for t in range(x):
            print n+t
            b[n+t]=-999

print b
```

However, when a 1 is located at the end of the list I get:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @hpnk85 if just [1] , what is expected result?

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case - for the elements at the end of the list the next element doesn't exist. You need to check for this special case in the inner loop, before you access the list:

```
if n+t >= len(b):
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
b = [(i, -999)[1 in a[max(0,n-x):n+1]] for n, i in enumerate(a)]
```

Produces:

```
# x = 2
[-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, -999, -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999]
# x = 1
[-999, -999, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, 3, 4, 5, -999, -999, 5, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999]
```

`(i, -999)[1 in a[max(0,n-x):n+1]]` translates to: Take `-999` if 1 can be found at this or the previous `x` indexes, else take `i` itself.

Answer (score 1):

My approach makes use of a variable `seen` whose value is cycling between 0, 1, 2:

```
def replace_element_and_next(seq, search, replace):
    seen = 0
    for x in seq:
        if x == search:
            yield replace
            seen = 1
        elif seen in [1, 2]:
            yield replace
            seen = (seen + 1) % 3
        else:
            yield x

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1]
print(','.join('%4d' % x for x in a))
b = replace_element_and_next(a, 1, -999)
print(','.join('%4d' % x for x in b))
```

Output:

```
   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   2,   3,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   1,   5,   5,   3,   2,   1,   3,   1
-999,-999,-999,   4,   5,   2,   3,-999,-999,-999,   4,   5,-999,-999,-999,   3,   2,-999,-999,-999
```

## Notes

- `seen` is initialized to 0
- The value of `seen` (0, 1, 2) means *I have seen the search term 0, 1, or 2 times*
- The expression `seen = (seen + 1) % 3` ensures that the value of `seen` is in the range of 0, 1, and 2
- The function `replace_element_and_next()` returns a generator object. If you want a list, do this:

  ```
  b = list(replace_element_and_next(a, 1, -999))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way is to use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
a=[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5,3,2,1,3,1]
new_a = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x:x == 1)]
final_a = list(itertools.chain(*[[-999] if a else [-999, -999, *b[2:]] for a, b in new_a]))
```

Output:

```
[-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, -999, -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999, -999]
```

Edit: Solution for Python2:

```
import itertools
a=[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5,3,2,1,3,1]
new_a = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x:x == 1)]
final_a = list(itertools.chain(*[[-999] if a else [-999, -999]+b[2:] for a, b in new_a]))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am also interested that the '1' value becomes -999
So the output looks like
[-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 1, -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999, -999]

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax: *b[2:]] ?

Comment: @hpnk85 `*` is unpacking for Python3. However, I will add a solution for Python2. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This could result in final_a having extra elements (which is easily fixed, of course)

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the index of element you want to edit, or i am sure the python idiom is it is better to beg for forgiveness than to ask for permission. You can just wrap a try statement around it and just pass when a specific error occurs.

```
b = a
x = 2 #number of continuous elements to browse 
for n,i in enumerate(a):
    if i==1:
        for t in range(x):
            print n+t
            try: b[n+t]=-999
            except IndexError:
                # either pass or append right? 
                b.append(-999)
                # pass
print b
```

but yeah the break that was suggested thing will save you some as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not described all the situations like what if there are two 1 at last then you want to ignore that or want to add that because that 1 is single and there are no other next two elements ,

But as you commented out :

> I am also interested that the '1' value becomes -999 So the output
>   looks like [-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 1,
>   -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999, -999]

So :

Here is very simple approach without making it complicated or importing any module:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5,3,2,1,3,1,1]


for i,j in enumerate(a):

    try:
        if j == 1:
            a[i] = -999
            a[i + 1] = -999
            a[i + 2] = -999

    except IndexError:
        pass

print(a)
```

output:

```
[-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, -999, -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999, -999]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers already given, one simple approach is two create a set `indices` of all the positions where `1` has to be replaced in `a`, then filter that set to make sure that no indices are invalid, such as accessing `a[21]` when the list size is only `20`. This is to make sure no indices go beyond the length of `a`, which will be prone to `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` errors.

At the end you can just replace each position found in `a` from this set.

Here is my take on it:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5,3,2,1,3,1]

indices = set()
for i, e in enumerate(a):
    if e == 1:
        indices.add(i)
        indices.add(i+1)
        indices.add(i+2)

pos = {x for x in indices if x < len(a)}

for i in pos:
    a[i] = -999

print(a)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, -999, -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999]
```

**Note:** Like most other answers, the above is `O(N)` time complexity. I also used sets instead of lists to store the indices as you can have no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Using `range()` and `len()`, you could try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5,3,2,1,3,1]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 1:
        if len(a) - i >= 2:
            a[i] = -999
            a[i+1] = -999
            a[i+2] = -999

print(a)

[-999, -999, -999, 4, 5, 2, 3, -999, -999, -999, 4, 5, -999, -999, -999, 3, 2, -999, -999, -999]
>>>
```